# Determining the direction of the force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum

[image]

Consider the above. Why must the force be defined to act upwards rather than acting downwards?

Consider defining the upwards direction as negative and the downwards direction as positive. We then have the following
$$\frac{-mv-mu}{t}$$
What direction would this force be acting? Would it not be downwards?

Answer (score 1):

You can call the 'upwards' direction +ve or -ve, but it remains the upwards direction. Positive and negative depends on your axes, which you are free to choose, but you can't change the fact that the force acts upwards.

In the same way, if you jump off a building, you could say your acceleration is positive or negative (depending on which sign you choose for 'downwards'), but you can't say you fall upwards. That would imply you escape Earth's gravity, go into orbit, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the axis in whichever way you want, which also includes positive direction.

Then you write equations with respect to the defined axes and calculate the force.

Considering 1D scenario, the calculated force can be either positive or negative. If it is positive, the force acts in the direction of the positive axis; if it is negative, it acts in the direction opposite to the positive axis.

---

As to why the resultant "collision" force acts upwards, the answer is simple: the "collision" force first stops the ball from going downwards (which means it must act in the direction opposite to "downwards") and then the ball even starts moving upwards.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\hat z$ be a unit vector pointing upwards then the change in momentum is $m\vec v_{\rm final} - m \vec v_{\rm initial} = mv_{\rm final} \,\hat z - m v_{\rm initial}\,(-\hat z)= (mv_{\rm final}+m v_{\rm initial})\hat z$, ie in an upward direction and thus that must be the direction of the force.